# JBoss AS 7.1.1 Remote Application Monitoring

Tags: jboss, jmx

atm I'm facing some problems when I'm trying to connect to my JBoss AS 7.1.1 (on a Linux-Server) via JMX remotely and monitor my Java-Apps from a Win-7 client. I can only see the standard JVM settings but no app-specific ones.

I learned that I have to include the jars in the Classpath while starting jvisualvm on my Windows 7 client.

that looks like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\jvisualvm.exe" -cp:a C:\Users\myuser\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules

But still it is not working...when I try to connect via:

service:jmx:remoting-jmx://:9999

Is there any special configuration I have to change in my JBoss server besides enabling jmx-management in standalone.xml?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `jvisualvm` is for profiling. Try `jconsole` instead. Also, port 9999 is by default the native cli management port. So maybe you wanted to try `jboss-cli`: `connect remotHost:9999`. And yes, you likely have to provide credentials for an `ApplicationRealm` user.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26762388/2087640