# Jmeter PerfMon Metrics collection on different jmx port

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

Wanted to post this because I searched around a lot and could not find a solution.

Using jmeter and ServerAgent (2.2.1), I was having trouble getting it work on a custom JMX port (not 4711). Per the documentation you need to specify the parameters like so:

```
By default the Server Agent will try to connect to JMX server at localhost with port 4711. If you started JMX server at different host/port or using authentication with username/password, please, use following additional parameters:

url=<hostname>\:<port>
user=<username>
password=<password>
Available JMX metric types:

gc-time - time spent in garbage collection, milliseconds (used method)
memory-usage - heap memory used by VM, bytes (method used)
memory-committed - heap memory committed by VM, bytes (method used)
memorypool-usage - heap memory pool usage, bytes (method used)
memorypool-committed - heap memory pool committed size, bytes (method used)
class-count - loaded class count in VM (used method)
compile-time - time spent in compilation, milliseconds (used method)
Examples:

gc-time - monitor GC time at localhost:4711
memory-usage:url=somehost.com\:4715 - use alternative hostname/password
class-count:url=somehost.com\:4715:user=apc:password=SecurityPlease123 - some secure setup access
```

[Source](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/)

So I tried that using

localhost 4444 JMX gc-time:url=localhost:9080

This however resulted in the server agent having the following stack trace

```
INFO    2017-02-23 20:53:51.352 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: jmx:gc-time:url=localhost\:9080
ERROR   2017-02-23 20:53:51.445 [kg.apc.p] (): Failed to get MX Bean data provider
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define JMX type
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.jmx.AbstractJMXDataProvider.getProvider(AbstractJMXDataProvider.java:48)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.JMXMetric.<init>(JMXMetric.java:42)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.AbstractPerfMonMetric.createMetric(AbstractPerfMonMetric.java:65)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.setUpMetrics(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:138)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:63)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processNextCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:101)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.read(PerfMonWorker.java:210)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processCommands(PerfMonWorker.java:97)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.AgentTool.processParams(AgentTool.java:72)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:175)
ERROR   2017-02-23 20:53:51.446 [kg.apc.p] (): Invalid metric specified: jmx
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get MX Bean data provider
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.JMXMetric.<init>(JMXMetric.java:45)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.AbstractPerfMonMetric.createMetric(AbstractPerfMonMetric.java:65)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.setUpMetrics(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:138)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:63)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.processNextCommand(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:101)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.read(PerfMonWorker.java:210)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processCommands(PerfMonWorker.java:97)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.AgentTool.processParams(AgentTool.java:72)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define JMX type
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.jmx.AbstractJMXDataProvider.getProvider(AbstractJMXDataProvider.java:48)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.JMXMetric.<init>(JMXMetric.java:42)
        ... 14 more
```

The solution, unbelievably, was to put the url portion first. Hopefully someone finds this page and time can be saved.

e.g.

url=localhost:9080:gc-time

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue, you are not using JMX port in your JMeter monitoring,but you might be using  application port , but JMeter monitoring required JMX port.

Verify your application servers for JMX port details. Below are most commonly used application servers and step to follow to get port details.

**"Tomcat":** In catalina.sh or setenv.sh file, look for  "Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port"=9004, if you are not seen this entry try to configure your tomcat server by following below link
https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/jconsole-jmx-remote-access-on-tomcat/

**Jboss:** In standalone.conf look for  "Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port"=9004, if you are not seen this entry try to configure your tomcat server by following below link
[Connect to JBoss 7 using VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135550/connect-to-jboss-7-using-visualvm).

Once you have JMX port, JMeter will be able to monitor.

```
Monitoring Demo App:


     1. Start you JMeter instance
     2. Start java application (New instance jmeter, cd {JMeter_home}/bin) using following command 

        java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6969 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar ApacheJMeter.jar

    3. Download jmeter_mon.jmx file from Github using [link][1]
    4. Open "jmeter_mon.jmx" file from JMeter instance 1.
    5. Start Server monitoring script sh {ServerAgent}/startAgent.sh 
    6. Run the Jmeter
```

Comment: Madhu, thanks for your response, but if you read the entire thing I posted the answer in my question as a reference for those who may have the same issue