# Unable remote connect Visualvm to JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, jboss

I'm using JBoss EAP 7.
And I configured the JBoss server.conf as mentioned in the 
[Connect to JBoss 7 using VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135550/connect-to-jboss-7-using-visualvm)

But I still got the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/Logmanger/Level
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:319)`enter code here`
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:507)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:348)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 4 more
```

Can someone please tell  what's I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you started VisualVM by placing `jboss-client.jar` in classpath ?

> ./visualvm -cp:a /path/to/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/client/jboss-client.jar